# How can I deliver a highly-curated, pre-configured VS Code editor experience for my enterprise organization?

Tags: visual-studio-code, synchronization, settings

Professionally, I work on a team whose mission is to improve the productivity of software engineers at my organization. Part of this work is improving the IDE / editor experience and integrate it more deeply into the business.

I'm aware that VS Code has two primary paradigms for settings:

- Workspace settings, which are more-or-less local to a specific folder on your file system
- User settings, which are globally applied, regardless of which workspace you are accessing

All of these settings are stored in one or more `*.json` files, in locations that are known to VS Code.

Knowing this, is there a preferred out-of-the-box way to support synchronizing broad settings, which plugins are installed, etc that I could leverage for my enterprise organization?

I've considered a process outside of VS Code to merge enterprise-curated settings into a user's `settings.json` file, but the UX around this is less than ideal.

Answer (score 0):

> Knowing this, is there a preferred out-of-the-box way to support synchronizing broad settings, which plugins are installed, etc that I could leverage for my enterprise organization?

Yes. [Profiles](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles) do that. ([feature added in VS Code 1.75](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_75#_profiles)), and you can get some synchronization going [by combining it](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/profiles#_do-profiles-sync-across-machines-via-settings-sync) with the settings sync feature, but I don't know if there's such thing as pushing profiles from some central source to multiple settings sync accounts.

---

As for workspace settings, there are settings that are intentionally not configurable inside workspace settings.json files- mostly things that have to do with visual appearances, which makes a lot of sense. I wouldn't want a workspace's settings messing with the visual appearance settings I set in my user settings.json file.

Workspaces can also list recommended extensions for the purposes of itself using a `.vscode/extensions.json` file. ([docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/extension-marketplace#_workspace-recommended-extensions)).

You can go a long way just using workspace settings.json and extensions.json, and usually.

Comment: Thank you! I had completely glossed over the Profiles feature in the docs